# Removing shutdown and sleep button from the Apple menu on Mavericks

Tags: macos

I'm trying to remove the "Sleep" and "Shutdown" entries from the Apple menu.
So far I managed to do it by editing `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/StandardMenus.nib/objects.xib` but that solution is quite ugly.
It can be a cause of some instabilities?

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabled -bool true
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabledWhileLoggedIn -bool True
```

but they don't seem to work anymore (I used this in Mountain Lion).
I wondered if there was any better way to do disable those entries.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is your Mac in a lab?

Comment: Some interesting commands here: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/disabling-the-sleep-command-in-the-apple-menu/, for anyone still interested.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about Shut Down but you can disable Sleep using pmset:

```
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1
```

This will gray out the Sleep menu item as well.

**Source**: [OS X Server: How to prevent sleep](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT200106)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.  The question is how to remove the command from the Apple menu, not prevent the Mac from sleeping. - From Review -

Comment: As mentioned in the linked article, it grays out the Sleep menu item too..  :)

Comment: Please add all the relevant information to your answers in order to make them more useful. Links may rot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot